# How can I increase margin between two particular groups? in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer

In Navigation drawer If we want to make changes we can create theme in styles then use it , For example textsize? if we increase text size of item it will apply all items text but i want to create margin between particular group
This is a sample from which i want to change my app drawer like this.
please help me...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution according to me is that you should get item with no title.

Add this to your navigation drawer list:

```
<item
        android:title="" />
```

Don't forget to disable the click on this item; otherwise, the navigation drawer will close. When clicked at this blank space.

Comment: how can i disable this item click @Ravi Bhardwaj