# Android - NavigationView menu - add margin between groups

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I have these two groups inside NavigationView menu XML:

```
<group>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_top"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_flame"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:title="@string/top_rated" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_latest"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_clock"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:title="@string/latest_uploads" />
</group>

<group>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_allvids"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_flame"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:title="@string/top_rated" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_allpics"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_shuffle"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:title="@string/random" />
</group>
```

I need to add space between them, the solution here: [How can I increase margin between two particular groups? in Navigation Drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46434468/how-can-i-increase-margin-between-two-particular-groups-in-navigation-drawer) is bad because the space is too much.

So how can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943213/how-to-control-navigationview-margin-between-menu-items

Comment: I've seen that, I need space between groups not items

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `dimens.xml`:

```
<dimen name="design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding">16dp</dimen>
```

(This value defines the top and bottom padding for the groups of the `com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView`)